# javascript regular expression to match {0}

Tags: javascript, regex

What will be the regular expression to match {0} in a piece of text?
so that if I have

```
 var temp = 'this is my {0} attempt';
```

I could use that regular expression in javascript to get the {0} out of 'temp', and replace with whatever text I want.

Thanks

Comment: I've answered to your question, but take this hint: if you google "javascript string replace" you get plenty of examples and alternatives. Google is your friend. Really.

Comment: @Giacomo the point of Stackoverflow is to be a site that contains information for Google searches to find!

Comment: Not when this information is already everywhere. Polluting S.O. with "how can I print an integer in C?" and "is there any way I can open a window in javascript" is not producing good, useful, reusable information. But here we are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
temp = temp.replace("{0}", "your text")
```

Regex is definitely not needed for this!

Ofcourse, you can do the following as well:

```
temp = temp.replace(/{\d+}/, "your text")
```

Response to @Giacomo:

```
temp = temp.replace("{\d+}", "your text")
```

will not replace anything. `{\d+}` is treated as a string and not regex

Comment: @Giacomo - uh? how? Anything in "" is treated as string and not regex

Answer (score 3):

If you want to replace with something based on what the number is inside the curly braces, you could do this:

```
var replaced = original.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g, function(_, digits) {
  return getReplacement(Number(digits));
});
```

You'd then write the function "getReplacement()" to return something based on the index from the original string.

Comment: This is a pretty ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
/\{\d\}/
```